# How do I get the menu on the right side of the screen back?

Tags: interface

I just started learning blender and was following the donut tutorial on youtube but I closed the menu that shows all the different options and settings on the right by accident. It is there if I start a new project, but on my current donut project, it is still missing. Can someone please tell me how to get this menu back? I included a picture, basically a "before" and I circled the part I am trying to get back. Please help[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new panel by moving your mouse e.g. to the lower left corner of another panel until a cross appears and then drag it up.

Then change the panel to "Properties"

[image]

Comment: ok but if I don't want these floating pink hexagons?

Comment: @moonboots : if you want to have a new panel - you will have that hexagons. You know - Nothing is for free. Everything has its prize.

Comment: And by the way - they are pink and cyan….